# jquery - Copy one row of table to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this portion of code:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            var row = $(this).closest('tr').html();
            $('#two').append('<tr>'+row+'</tr>');
        }
    });

    function clearSel(){
        $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { 
            this.checked = false; 
        }); 
        $("#two").empty();
    }
```

This code works fine on a local folder. When I put it on a web app on xampp, just the clearSel() function works. The table one content is generated from a AJAX request on a php file which return rows. In first stage of accessing the page both tables exists, but are empty. I don't understand why on xampp fails. Some suggestions? Thank you.

[EDIT] The code provided of Super User works fine. I am newbie, i didnt know anything about event delegation(i will study) . Thank you for answer!!!!

Comment: You can skip `.html()` and directly append `object` to your desired `div#two`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `event delegation` here, check updated code below..
[detail reference](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr').html();
        $('#two').append('<tr>'+row+'</tr>');
    }
});

function clearSel(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() { 
        this.checked = false; 
    }); 
    $("#two").empty();
}
```